# Unit test view rendering time in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, rendering

I have a requirement on my project that all views should render themselves in under 500 milliseconds, which does not take into account the time spent binding the data on the view and/or executing calls to the backend.

Just the control rendering time should be measured.

I saw [many similar questions here in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=measure%20wpf) and other places but none that truly helps me with the problem as they are advising the use of a profiler or code outside of tests.

What I have so far is the following unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void View_WaitForLoadedEvent_ElapsedTimeDoesNotExceedAllowedLimit()
{
    // Arrange.
    var dispatcherAction =
        new System.Action(() =>
            {
                this.stopWatch.Stop();
                this.elapsedMilliseconds = this.stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

                Dispatcher.ExitAllFrames();
            });

    this.stopWatch.Start();
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Loaded, dispatcherAction);

    // Act.
    var view = new HomeView();

    Dispatcher.Run();

    // Assert.
    Assert.IsTrue(this.elapsedMilliseconds < RenderTimeTests.MaxAllowedRenderingMilliseconds,
                  RenderTimeTests.GetFormattedErrorMessage(view.ToString(), this.elapsedMilliseconds));
}
```

Now, after executing this test 10 times in a row I got the following values for the `this.elapsedMilliseconds` variable:

153, 140, 109, 144, 131, 116, 124, 127, 139, 106.
So on average it takes 128.9 milliseconds to load.

The values are fairly constant, but when doing the test recommended in most of the answers for the similar questions here in StackOverflow the values are different.

The recommended test is as follows:

```
public HomeView()
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();

    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
        DispatcherPriority.Loaded,
        new System.Action(() =>
        {
            sw.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("Took " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
        }));

    this.InitializeComponent();
}
```

And this gives me the following values on the message box:

206, 213, 218, 203, 210, 209, 210, 210, 222, 230. On average this is 213.1.

It may not seems as much but these values tell me that the actual rendering time is 60% higher than what the automated test tells me!

Finally, I decided to remove the `MessageBox.Show(...)` method and replace it with `Debug.WriteLine(...)` just to see if there was any difference (although the watch should not be counting anymore at this point) and I got the following values:

207, 194, 212, 207, 211, 201, 217, 215, 214, 214. Giving an average of 209.2, much closer to the other execution than to the unit test results.

The application is using the `Caliburn.Micro` [mvvm](/questions/tagged/mvvm) framework and `LightInject` for injection dependency.

And so this brings me to the question, how reliable are these tests in reality?

Comment: Maybe performing tasks asynchronously might be useful here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I believe I found the answer (partially at least) to my own question:

The difference in time is because when measuring via the unit test, only the view (xaml + cs) loading time was being taken into account.

When doing it through the view constructor, the view model was being loaded as well before the stopwatch stop counting!

Another thing to keep in mind is the build option. When executing the unit test without debugging it, the time dropped considerably (the view in question went from 128.9ms to 90ms on average).

Even though I believe I found my answer, I'll leave the question in case anyone has a better answer or way to measure than the ones I used.